# Return a Calculated Field from a Cross-Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

I am using sp_addlinkedsrvlogin to execute a cross-join query on two different SQL Servers (our payroll server and our production server).  The first query returns how many hours each employee logged on the time clock (payroll server).  The second query returns how many hours that same employee was logged into work orders.

I would like to create a calculated column called Employee_Utilization that divides WO_Hours by Payroll_Hours.  Any tips on how to do this in this Cross Join query would be great.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'PAYROLLSERVER', 'false', NULL, '**', '**********'
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        C.EMPLOYEE AS [Employee ID]
        ,E.FIRSTNAME
        ,E.LASTNAME
        ,C.[PEREND]
        ,C.[CATEGORY]
        ,C.[AUDTORG]
        ,C.[EARDEDTYPE]
        ,C.[EARDEDDATE]
        ,SUM(DISTINCT C.[HOURS]) AS [Payroll_Hours]
    FROM [PAYROLLSERVER].[SagePayroll].[dbo].[UPCHKD] C JOIN [PAYROLLSERVER01].[SagePayroll_SUD].[dbo].[UPHHAU] E ON C.EMPLOYEE = E.EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE C.CATEGORY = '2' AND C.PEREND = '20221210'
    GROUP BY
        C.EMPLOYEE
        ,E.FIRSTNAME
        ,E.LASTNAME
        ,C.[PEREND]
        ,C.[CATEGORY]
        ,C.[AUDTORG]
        ,C.[EARDEDTYPE]
        ,C.[EARDEDDATE] 
) A
CROSS JOIN
(
     SELECT [Employee ID],SUM([Labor Run Hours]) AS [WO_Hours]
     FROM [********].[*********].[dbo].[WorkOrders_Labor]
     WHERE [Date Worked] > '11/26/22' AND [Date Worked] < '12/11/22'
     GROUP BY [Employee ID] 
) B
WHERE A.[Employee ID] = B.[Employee ID]
```

[image: Current Result Set]``

Comment: `WHERE A.[Employee ID] = B.[Employee ID]` -- that's not a cross join, but just a normal inner join.

Comment: You can just add `, [WO_Hours] / [Payroll_Hours] as Employee_Utilization` in the second line to compute that value, right after the `*`.

Comment: Consider being explicit on the join by changing `CROSS JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` to `ON`. See also Alan Betrand's [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).